# So many Binlog_dump connections in Processlist?

Tags: mysql, meteor, tcp, docker

We are using Meteor and MySQL stack (numtel) and trying to connect to 3 databases simultaneously. One database is sitting with the application as localhost (mysql version 5.5.44). Other on is on another EC2 machine as native server (mysql version 5.5.44). And third one is in Docker container (mysql version 5.6.26).

Our meteor application stops intermittently so we have started debugging it. We have checked processlist on all the three servers but we can see only too many binlog_dump connection in dockerize ones. It says"

> Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated

It reaches to maximum connection limit of 15000 now. We have killed them all and application starts again. But this is happening every now and then. Any idea? If you need, I can share some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binlog_dump` connections come from a replication slave client. The slave connects to the master and requests a dump of the binary log so it can use it to replicate. This could be another instance of MySQL acting as a replication slave, `mysqlbinlog` utility, or a third-party (or your own) tool that uses the same protocol.

Is it possible that you have a MySQL slave host that is misconfigured? E.g. `server_id` set to the same value as that of the master? Are you using any third-party tools that might attempt to use internal MySQL replication facilities? Could you possibly have a rogue script that runs `mysqlbinlog`?

You can trace down the source IP and the port of the originating connection via `SHOW PROCESSLIST` - look in the `Host` column. Then log in to the offending machine and use the appropriate utility (`netstat` on Unix-like systems) to track down the process which made the connection, then take the appropriate action to make sure that process does not run again.